# Want to display as table view

Tags: php, html, css

Here I want to change the UI design of this code.I need to display the belows are in table view.Here in code some fields have same names that is name ml,name en and info ml,info en and details ml,details en.that two similer fields should be in same line

```
          <div class="form quick-post">    

         <!-- Edit deity Details-->

             <form class="form-horizontal" action="deity_manage.php" method="post">

           <!-- Deity id -->
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="title"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="deity_id" id="title" value="<?php echo $deity_id;?>">
              </div>
         </div>


     <!-- Name ml -->
  <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="title">Name Ml</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deity_name_ml" id="deity_name_ml" value="<?php echo $deity_name_ml;?>">

     <!--Name en-->
   <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Name En</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deity_name_en" id="deity_name_en" value="<?php echo $deity_name_en; ?>">
           <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>
    <!--Info ml-->
             <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Info Ml</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="info_ml" ><?php echo $info_ml;?></textarea>
       <!--Info en-->
       <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Info En</label>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="info_en" ><?php echo $info_en;?></textarea>
    <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>

    <!--details_ml -->
      <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Details Ml</label>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="details_ml" ><?php echo $details_ml;?></textarea>

<!--Details en-->
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Details En</label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="details_en" ><?php echo $details_en;?></textarea>
         <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>

           <!--Mantra ml-->
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Mantra Ml</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mantra_ml" id="mantra_ml" value="<?php echo $mantra_ml;?>">

      <!--Mantra en-->
         <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Mantra En</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mantra_en" id="mantra_en" value="<?php echo $mantra_en;?>">
       <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>


             <!--God-->
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">God</label>
              <select multiple="true" name="god_id">
  <?php while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                              <option <?php if($row['god_id'] == $god_id) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> value="<?php echo $row['god_id'];?>">
                                                <?php echo $row['god_name_en']; ?>
                                              </option>
                                              <?php } ?>
                                              </option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>


                                    <!--Display order-->

                                          <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Display Order</label>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="display_order" id="display_order" value="<?php echo $display_order;?>">
                                          <div style="padding-top:25px"></div>

                                          <!-- Buttons -->
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                             <!-- Buttons -->
                                             <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-9">

                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="submit">  Save  </button>

                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </form>
                                      </div>


                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the labels and input types inside the  tag

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="content">Details En</label>
</td>
<td>
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="details_en" ><?php echo $details_en;?></textarea>
</td>
<Label
```